# ScrollView through Interface Builder, ScrollView not scrolling completely till bottom

Tags: iphone, ios, uiscrollview

I am creating a `ScrollView` through InterFace Builder using the techniques shown in [this tutorial](http://agilewarrior.wordpress.com/2012/05/18/uiscrollview-examples/?year=2012&monthnum=05&day=18&like=1&_wpnonce=27447bba97).
However I am not able to scroll till the very bottom of the `scrollView.`

I have implemented a `scrollView` as described using interface builder. My `scrollView` is much longer in height than the `mainView.` I want the `scrollView` to appear only in the bottom half of my main view (view1). Therefore I have created another sub-view(view2) and then added the `scrollView` to `View2`, simultaneously I have added `View2` to `View1`. Now the scrollView is appearing in my main view, however I am not being able to scroll to the bottom of the scroll view. The `scrollView` scrolls to a certain limit, but not able to scroll to the bottom limit of the scroll view. 
Somehow I found out that in interfaceBuilder if I increase the height of the scrollView at the bottom (leaving a huge blank space at the bottom of `scrollView` in interfaceBuilder) , then I am able to scroll everything !! , and the huge blank space also does not show up in the iOS simulator. !!!!!! I want to know where I am doing wrong. !!!!

Answer (score 2):

The size of the scroll view doesn't have to be large. If you want it to scroll, you set it's content size to the size of the content. If the content size is larger than the frame of the scroll view, it will scroll:

`scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(width, height);`

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Set the contentSize and ContentOffSet of Scrollview properly.

Comment: I have set contentSize , but not ContentOffset .

Answer (score 0):

You have to set your `scrollView` content size according to your data.

```
[scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(width,height)];
```

And don't increase your scrollView height , just fixed it and then `setcontentSize`.

Answer (score -1):

You need to make the scroolView size equal to the area in which you want the scrollView but set its content size to the size of your data to be displayed in the scrollView. Hope this might help